# Check if an ArrayList contains the same element as another ArrayList

Tags: java, android-studio, arraylist

I have used some other answers to get a solution to my problem. But I am wondering if there is a way to improve this further?

```
// Copy the masterList ArrayList and then sort in ascending order and then make a third 
// ArrayList and loop through to add the 8 lowest values to this list.
ArrayList<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList<>(Calculator.masterList);
Collections.sort(sortedList);
ArrayList<Integer> lowEight = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lowEight.add(sortedList.get(i));
}
```

```
// Set TextView as the value of index 0 in masterList ArrayList, check if lowEight 
// ArrayList contains the element that is the same as masterList index 0 and if
// so highlight s1 textview green.
s1.setText("Score 1 is " + String.format("%d", Calculator.masterList.get(0)));
if (lowEight.contains(Calculator.masterList.get(0))) {
    s1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```

This works to an extent by highlighting the values that are in both `masterList` and `lowEight` but for example if the number 7 is in `lowEight` and appears 9 times in `masterList` it will highlight all 9 occurences. Is there a way to move the exact object from `masterList` to `sortedList` and then to `lowEight` and then a method to check the object and not just the value?

Answer (score 0):

Let me provide a more concise example of what you're asking.  Let us take the following code:

```java
ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>() {
    {
        add(5);
        add(5);
    }
};

ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add(list1.get(0));
list1.forEach((i) -> System.out.println(list2.contains(i)));
```

The output is:

```
true
true
```

But you would expect it to be:

```
true
false
```

Because the first and second element are different objects.  The problem here is that although they are *different* objects, they are *equal* objects.  The way the Integer class is written in Java, any Integer is equal to another Integer if they represent the same value.  When you run the `contains()` method, it sees that the list does indeed contain an object equal to the one you provided (in this case they both represent a value of 5), and so it returns true.  So how do we solve this problem?  How do we tell one Integer object from another?  I would write your own "Integer" class.  Something like "MyInteger".  Here's a very simple implementation you could use:

```java
public class MyInteger {
    private final int i;

    public MyInteger(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public int toInt() {
        return i;
    }
}
```

And then when we use it in our ArrayList code:

```java
ArrayList<MyInteger> list1 = new ArrayList<MyInteger>() {
    {
        add(new MyInteger(5));
        add(new MyInteger(5));
    }
};

ArrayList<MyInteger> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add(list1.get(0));
list1.forEach((i) -> System.out.println(list2.contains(i)));
```

We get our expected output:

```
true
false
```

This works because our new MyInteger class implicitly uses the default `equals()` method, which always returns false.  In other words, no two MyInteger objects are ever equal.  You can apply this same principle to your code.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to give that great explanation! I will give this a go. Thanks

Comment: @JamesSmith No problem!  If you have any questions re: this answer, feel free to ask, and if this answer ends up helping you, please come back and mark it as accepted.